# Explained variance score vs $R^2$ score

Tags: regression, correlation, regression-coefficients, r-squared, coefficient-of-variation

I came across [explained variance score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#explained-variance-score) and $R^2$ score in scikit learn docs.

Docs defines exaplained variance score as:

> $\text{explained variance} (y,\hat{y})=1-\frac{Var\{y-\hat{y}\}}{Var\{y\}}$

which I feel equates to $$1-\frac{\sum(y-\hat{y}-\overline{(y-\hat{y})})^2}{\sum(y-\bar{y})^2}\tag I$$

Docs then define $R^2$ score as follows:

> $$R^2(y,\hat{y})=1-\frac{\sum(y-\hat{y})^2}{\sum(y-\bar{y})^2} \tag{II}$$

The difference between equation $\rm (I)$ and $\rm (II)$ is that equation $\rm (I)$ has $"-\overline{(y-\hat{y})}"$ in the numerator, while equation $\rm (II)$ does not. I have learnt from the various sources what different values of $R^2$ indicate:

- $R^2<0→$ horizontal line explains the data better than the model, in other words, the chosen model does not follow the trend of the data
- $R^2=0→$ horizontal line explains the data as well as the model, i.e. model has no explanatory value
- $R^2>0→$ model explains the data better than the horizontal line
- $R^2=1→$ means the model / regression line explains 100% of the variation in the response variable. This will be the case when all the data points lie precisely on the regression line

**Q1.** What to make sense of different values of "explained variance" and why?
**Q2.** Also, the doc points to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_variation) wiki page which does not give formula in equation $\rm (I)$. Why so?
**Q3.** How the two quantities are related intuitively?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378176/python-sci-kit-learn-metrics-difference-between-r2-score-and-explained-varian

Comment: Put a lot time on that stackoverflow question. Accepted answer was quite convoluted in code. Also found second highest rated answer quite confusing. This is what I made sense from it and after some thinking, but ***need confirmation***: **Q3.** "Explained variance" is unbiased version of $R^2$ obtained by subtracting $\overline{(y-\hat{y})^2}$ from the numerator of $R^2$. **Q1.** Since "explained variance" is just an unbiased version of $R^2$, its different values carry same meaning as explained in question for $R^2$. **Q2.** Not sure why. They might just have missed it.

Answer (score 1):

The explained variance formula compares the variance of your residuals to the variance, which sounds great. However, the documentation says exactly why such a metric is not as helpful as it might appear.

> The difference between the explained variance score and the R² score, the coefficient of determination is that when the explained variance score does not account for systematic offset in the prediction.

For instance, the explained variance function will see something like $y=(1,2,3,4)$ and $\hat y = (8, 9, 10, 11)$ and give a perfect score despite the predictions being awful. The formula $(II)$ would correctly flag this as problematic.

```r
formula_1 <- function(y, yhat){
  ybar <- mean(y)
  return(
    1
    -
      var(y - yhat)
    /
      var(y - ybar)
  )
}
formula_2 <- function(y, yhat){
  ybar <- mean(y)
 return(
   1
   -
     sum((y - yhat)^2)
   /
     sum((y - ybar)^2)
 ) 
}
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
yhat <- y + 7
formula_1(y, yhat) # I get 1, indicating a perfect fit
formula_2(y, yhat) # I get -38.2, indicating a terrible fit
```

This comes down to the fact that for any random variable $X$ with a finite variance and any $r\in\mathbb R$, $\text{var}(X) = \text{var}(X + r)$, yet $X = X+r$ does not hold in general, and this explained variance measure of performance does not catch such situations (which the `sklearn` $R^2$ function will catch).

Where the explained variance score could be useful is if you compare it to the $R^2$. If explained variance is good but $R^2$ is not, it could indicate systematic bias in the predictions, and you might be able to remedy this.

Note that the two can coincide, such as for in-sample predictions for an OLS linear regression.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
formula_1 <- function(y, yhat){
  ybar <- mean(y)
  return(
    1
    -
      var(y - yhat)
    /
      var(y - ybar)
  )
}
formula_2 <- function(y, yhat){
  ybar <- mean(y)
  return(
    1
    -
      sum((y - yhat)^2)
    /
      sum((y - ybar)^2)
  ) 
}
x <- runif(N, -2, 2)
y <- x + rnorm(N) + 7
L <- lm(y ~ x)
yhat <- predict(L)
formula_1(y, yhat) # I get 0.5379571
formula_2(y, yhat) # I get 0.5379571
```